# Amazon Public IPv4 address failed to connect (server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

my site has been online for awhile on Amazon EC2 and for some reason the Public IPv4 address supplied by Amazon no longer connects and loads my website, I have tried restarting, stopping, but it wont connect to this ip address and in turn wont load the website.

Amazon public ip which wont connect is   54.165.234.79  I was wondering if there was a way to replace it for a new working ip from amazon and replace this one which is broken.

Unsure how to proceed, apart from moving my site to a new server elsewhere.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Can you confirm that the instance still has the same public IP? If you are not using elastic IP addresses, your EC2 public IP can change when the instance is stopped and started again.

Comment: Hiya, it has changed the IP address but it is still failing, it changed it to this, but for some reason it still wont connect.   52.23.183.9   I dont understand, i have not changed anything and the UK site is still up and working, but the USA is still not connecting. I will probably ditch this Amazon, dont see any other option.

Comment: If anyone could recommend an alternative to Amazon EC2 it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that it was working before but not working now, please check the following.

Run the following command to verify that there aren't rules blocking traffic:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
```

If the preceding command indicates blocked traffic, remove the rule or add a rule allowing traffic for that specific port. In the following example, replace examplerule with the new rule and port 80 with your specific port number.

```
$ sudo iptables -D examplerule
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j ACCEPT
```

For Windows Server default firewalls, run the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all
```

If the preceding command indicates blocked traffic, then remove the old rule, or add a new rule allowing traffic for that specific port. In the following example, replace port 80 with your specific port number.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

Also check the following -

1. The route table that is associated with your instance’s subnet has a default route to an internet gateway (0.0.0.0/0).
2. The internet gateway that is associated with the route isn't deleted.
3. The security group that's attached to the instance’s elastic network interface has rules allowing outbound internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0) for your ports and protocols.
4. The network access control list (network ACL) that is associated with the instance's subnet has rules allowing both outbound and inbound traffic to the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive post, iv not setup this amazon EC2 so have little knowledge on any of the above, may have to move the site to a new server, the reason for the fault i found out was Amazon, apparently several websites on US-East 1 have gone down, and are still down.